# HashMap получить все свойства из объекта

Tags: java

Есть hashmap, который состоит из строки и объекта. Строка = название. Объект = свойства. Не могу понять, как можно вытащить значения из объекта, если у него больше чем одно свойство. Для объекта не работает метод size() или lenght(). Прошу помочь.

```
HashMap<String, Object> newPost = (HashMap<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Object нельзя заменить на более конкретную реализацию из за особенностей проекта?

Comment: Мне сервис так данные отдает( я бы с радостью

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Вот Ваши свойства");
foreach (Map.Entry<String, Object> s : snapshots.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(s.getKey() + ":");
    Map<Object, Object> properties = (Map<Object, Object>)s.getValue();
    foreach (Map.Entry<Object, Object> p : properties.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("    " + p.getKey() + ": " + p.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("    Итого " + properties.size() + " свойств(а)");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось взять свойства, премного благодарен!

Comment: А может быть подскажите, как вытащить из этого списка, например, второе свойство и 4-ое? А остальные не трогать.

Comment: Из хешей значения вытаскиваются не по порядковому номер (потому что там в принципе не определено понятие порядка), а по ключу. Если  Вам нужен ID и PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE, то так и пишите p.get("ID") и p.get("PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE");

Comment: Еще лучше, тогда можно отпустить второй foreach! Спасибо за помощь!